# How to create a new column based on a regex match across all columns?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr, dplyr

I want to search for a regex pattern across all my columns and if there's a match, create a new column with "Match", otherwise "No Match."

When filtering, I was able to do this with

`filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., '(?i)string.*c5')))`

But when I tried

`mutate(match = if_else(any_vars(str_detect(., '(?i)string.*c5')), "Match", "No Match"))`

I get a

> "condition must be a logical vector, not an `any_vars` object" error.

That makes sense, but I haven't figured out how to shuffle functions around to get it done. Note that not all my columns are strings, but hopefully that's not an issue.

I read through a few answers but none of those worked--`c_across` and `rowsum` didn't work either (used in other answer on the site).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `if_any` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>%
  mutate(match = if_else(if_any(.fns = ~str_detect(., '(?i)string.*c5')), "Match", "No Match"))
```